# SWRevealController TableView scrolls through status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using the SWRevealController library as my menu on the left side. It uses a tableView to show the menu items, everything works fine except for the scrolling. When I scroll down the tableView scrolls through the status bar.

I have tried adding the following line of code in the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear, but it doesn't change anything.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

To give you an idea, this is what's happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhn42.jpg

Comment: Give your tableview.frame=CGRectMake(0,20, self.tableview.frame.size.width, self.tableview..frame.size.height);

Comment: This kinda works, but not really... Now my tableView is a bit too short, and the last row won't display properly.

Comment: Try to decrease your tableview height.it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new view controller with a container view inside it. I've hooked the container to the original table view controller menu and switched the segue to the view controller with the container. Everything works fine now, I can resize the container and the menu will adapt automatically.